# Navbar collapses but is not showing "collapsed menu edition"

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the navbar menu of bootstrap and it shows good in desktop version, but in tablet and mobile, when it's shows the collapse menu, the dropdown menu it's the same that the desktop version, instead the mobile version should appear like so:

[image: It collapses but shows desktop version]

**HTML:**

```
  <nav class="navbar navbar-simelsa">
  <div class="container">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
       <div class="menu-text hidden-lg hidden-md hidden-sm">Menú<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed navbar-bottom" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-simelsa">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-center" id="navbar-simelsa">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="inicio"><a href="#">Inicio</a></li>
        <li class="nosotros"><a href="#">Nosotros</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown servicios">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Servicios <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
       <li class="productos"><a href="#">Productos</a></li>
        <li class="noticias"><a href="#">Noticias</a></li>
        <li class="contacto"><a href="#">Contacto</a></li>
      </ul>
        <li class="lang navbar-right nav navbar-nav"><a href="#">ESP | ENG</a></li>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

**CSS:**

```
@media (min-width: 1024px) {

.slick-prev, .slick-next {
    top: -12% !important;
    }
}
@media (max-width: 1024px) {

.header-bg {
    background: none !important;
}

.slick-prev, .slick-next {
  top: -13% !important;
  }
#navbar-simelsa a {
    font-size: 0.8em !important;

}

.slider-bottom {
  background-position: -35px -479px !important;
}
.box-content-carousel:hover .slider-bottom {
  background-position: -33px -499px !important;

}
}


@media (max-width: 768px) {

.footer-copyright {
    margin-left: 0px !important;
}
#navbar-simelsa a {
  font-size: 0.6em !important;
}
#navbar-simelsa ul.navbar-nav li {
  margin-right: 10px !important;
}
}
@media (max-width: 640px) {

.header-bg {
   /* margin: 0 auto; */
     background-image:url('../images/header-img.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 500px 0;
    height: 113px !important;
}

.social {
    margin-top: 10px !important;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    text-align: center;
}

#layerslider .ls-s-1 {
height: 60px !important;
}
.footer-logo {
    padding-top: 30px;
}

.slider-bottom {
  background-position: -55px -479px !important;
}
.box-content-carousel:hover .slider-bottom {
  background-position: -53px -499px !important;

}

}


@media (max-width: 480px) {

  .title-container-inicio {
      font-size: 1.3em !important;
  }
.footer-copyright  {

    font-size: 0.7em !important;

}

#layerslider .ls-s-1 {

    height: 40px !important;

}

.slider-bottom {
  background-position: -40px -479px !important;
}
.box-content-carousel:hover .slider-bottom {
  background-position: -43px -499px !important;

}


  .slick-prev, .slick-next {
  top: -13% !important;
  }

.box-content-carousel:hover .slider-bottom {
  background-position: -38px -499px !important;

} 

}
@media (max-width: 479px) {
.slider-bottom {
  background-position: 22px -479px !important;

    }
    .box-content-carousel:hover .slider-bottom {
  background-position: 24px -499px !important;

} 
.box-content-carousel img {
  margin-left: auto !important;
  margin-right: auto !important;
  }
    .slick-prev, .slick-next {
  top: -11% !important;
  }

  }

@media (max-width: 320px) {

    .slick-prev, .slick-next {
  top: -11% !important;
  }
  }


@media (min-width: 640px) and (max-width: 768px) {

.box-content-carousel h2 {
    font-size: 1.1em !important;
}
}

html {
    height: 100%;
}

body {
        height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(GradientType=0,startColorstr=#dbeef4, endColorstr=#fff);
 background-image:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #dbeef4 40%, #fff 50%);
 background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #dbeef4 40%, #fff 50%);
 background-image:-ms-linear-gradient(top, #dbeef4 40%, #fff 50%);
 background-image:linear-gradient(top, #dbeef4 40%, #fff 50%);
 background-image:-o-linear-gradient(top, #dbeef4 40%, #fff 50%);
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, right top, right bottom, color-stop(40%,#dbeef4), color-stop(50%,#fff));
   }

.nav .open>a, .nav .open>a:hover, .nav .open>a:focus {
    background: transparent !important;
}
.header-logo {
    background-color: #33add3;
    width: 100%;
 box-shadow: inset 0 -21px 19px -24px #808080;
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 -21px 19px -24px #808080;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 -21px 19px -24px #808080;
}
.header-bg {
   /* margin: 0 auto; */
     background-image:url('../images/header-img.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 500px 0;
    height: 133px;
}
#navbar-simelsa .lang a {
    color: #22a6cf;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif !important;
}
.lang {
    border-right: 0px !important;
    border-left: 0px !important;
    margin-right: 10px !important;
    line-height: 3em;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.logo {
    margin-top: 20px;
}

.nopadding {
   padding: 0 !important;
   margin: 0 !important;
}

.social ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 5px;

}

.social ul {
    list-style-type: none !important;
}

.social {
    margin-top: 73px;
}

#navbar-simelsa ul.navbar-nav li:first-child {
  border-left: 1px solid #dfdfdf;
  padding-left: 35px;

}
#navbar-simelsa ul.navbar-nav li {
  margin-right: 20px;
  border-right: 1px solid #dfdfdf;
  padding-left: 15px;
  height: 26px;
}

.dropdown-menu .divider {
  height: 1px;
  margin: -6px 0px 13px 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #e5e5e5;
}

.dropdown-menu li:first-child {
    padding-top: 10px;

}
.navbar-simelsa {
        background: #f2f2f2;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    margin-bottom: 2px !important;
}
#navbar-simelsa a:hover, #navbar-simelsa a:active, #navbar-simelsa a:focus {
        background-color: transparent;
}
#navbar-simelsa a {
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif !important;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 1em;
    line-height: 0em;
    font-weight: 200;
    color: #464646;

}
#navbar-simelsa ul {
margin-bottom: 10px;
margin-top: 10px;

}
#navbar-simelsa {
    text-align: left !important;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .navbar .navbar-nav {
        display: inline-block;
        float: none;
        vertical-align: top;
    }

    .navbar .navbar-collapse {
        text-align: center;
    }
}


#navbar-simelsa .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu>li {
  color: pink !important; 
    display: block;
  clear: both;
  font-weight: 400;
  padding-left: 0px !important;
  line-height: 1.42857143;
  color: #333;
  white-space: nowrap;
    margin-right: 0px !important;
}

.menu-text {
      border: 1px solid #D2D2D2;
  height: 45px;
  font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  color: #939393;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
.navbar-bottom {
    position: relative !important;
    margin-top: 0px !important;
    border: 0px !important;
    padding-top: 5px;
}

.navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
  display: block;
  width: 22px;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: #939393;
  border-radius: 1px;
}


#navbar-simelsa ul.navbar-nav li.divider {

    height: 1px !important;

}
.inicio {
    background-position: 18px 2px;
}

.nosotros {
    background-position: 0 -24px;
}

.noticias {
    background-position: 0 -105px;
}

.contacto {
    background-position: 0 -132px;
}

.servicios {
    background-position: 0 -50px;
}

.productos {
    background-position: 0 -79px;
}

.inicio, .nosotros, .noticias, .contacto, .servicios, .productos, .calendar, .slick-prev, .slick-next, .slider-bottom, .container-bottom-bg, .certified {
      background-image:url('../images/sprites.png');
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

@-webkit-keyframes swing
{
    15%
    {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(5px);
        transform: translateX(5px);
    }
    30%
    {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(-5px);
       transform: translateX(-5px);
    } 
    50%
    {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(3px);
        transform: translateX(3px);
    }
    65%
    {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(-3px);
        transform: translateX(-3px);
    }
    80%
    {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(2px);
        transform: translateX(2px);
    }
    100%
    {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
        transform: translateX(0);
    }
}
@keyframes swing
{
    15%
    {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(5px);
        transform: translateX(5px);
    }
    30%
    {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(-5px);
        transform: translateX(-5px);
    }
    50%
    {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(3px);
        transform: translateX(3px);
    }
    65%
    {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(-3px);
        transform: translateX(-3px);
    }
    80%
    {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(2px);
        transform: translateX(2px);
    }
    100%
    {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
        transform: translateX(0);
    }
}

.social ul li:hover
{
        -webkit-animation: swing 1s ease;
        animation: swing 1s ease;
        -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
        animation-iteration-count: 1;
}

/* LayerSlides */

#layerslider .ls-s-1 {
    background: #33add3;
    width: 284px;
    height: 260px;
    top: 45px !important;
    left: 60px !important;
    padding: 30px 20px 30px 35px;
}

#layerslider .ls-s-1 .title-box-slider {

    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif !important;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: #fff;
    line-height: 1.4em;
    font-size: 1.5em !important;

}

#layerslider .ls-s-1 p.desc {
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif !important;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: #1b1c21;
    line-height: 2em !important;
    font-size: 0.95em !important;

}    

.hr-img {
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 25px;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
}

.welcome {
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif !important;
    color: #999999;     
}
.welcome h1 {
    font-weight: 200;
    font-size: 2.1em;
}
.welcome p {
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    line-height: 1.7em;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
}

.news {
    background: #e3ebed;
    min-height: 113px;
}

.news-img {
        overflow: hidden;

}
.news img {
      -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease; /* Safari and Chrome */
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease; /* Firefox */
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease; /* IE 9 */
    -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease; /* Opera */
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
.news:hover img {
      -webkit-transform:scale(1.25); /* Safari and Chrome */
    -moz-transform:scale(1.25); /* Firefox */
    -ms-transform:scale(1.25); /* IE 9 */
    -o-transform:scale(1.25); /* Opera */
     transform:scale(1.25);
}
.calendar {
    background-position: 0 -333px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    color: #33add3;
    font-size: 0.8em;
    font-weight: 300;    

}
.box-text {
    padding: 10px;
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif !important;
}
.box-text p {
    margin-top: 10px;
    font-size: 1em;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: #000;
}
.nopadding {
   padding: 0 !important;
   margin: 0 !important;
}

.title-container-inicio {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #f2f2f2;
    font-size: 1.6em;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif !important;
    color: #464646;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}
.box-news {
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
}

/* Slider 2 */

.box-content-carousel {
    width: 268px;
    margin-right: 30px;
}
.slider-2 {
    margin-left: 15px;
}

.slick-prev.slick-disabled {
  background-position: 0 -416px !important;

}
.slick-next.slick-disabled {
  background-position: 0 -446px !important;

}
.slick-prev, .slick-next {
    width: 25px !important;
    height: 25px !important
}

.slick-next {
  right: 5px !important;
  background-position: 0 -356px !important;
}

.slick-prev {
  right: 35px !important;
  background-position: 0 -386px !important;
}

.box-content-carousel h2, .box-content-carousel p {
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif !important;
  color: #838484;    
  font-weight: 200 !important;

}

.box-content-carousel h2 {
    font-size: 1.2em;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.slider-img {
    border: 3px solid transparent;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
.box-content-carousel:hover .slider-img {
    border: 3px solid #33add3;
    border-radius: 3px;
}

.box-content-carousel:hover {
    cursor: pointer;

}
.slider-bottom {
  background-position: 0 -479px;
  padding-top: 13px;
  display: block;
    -o-transition: all .5s;
  -moz-transition: all .5s;
   -webkit-transition: all .5s; 
  -ms-transition: all .5s;
}

.box-content-carousel:hover .slider-bottom {
  background-position: 2px -499px;

}

/* Footer */

.footer {
    background: #f5f6f6;
}

.container-bottom-bg {
  background-position: 73px -524px !important;
  padding-top: 20px;
  display: block;
  width: 738px;

}    

.footer-copyright {
    margin-left: 100px;
}

.footer-copyright, .footer-copyright a {
    color: #33add3;
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif !important;
    font-weight: 500 !important;
    font-size: 1em;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin-top: 15px;

}
.link-footer-col {
    max-width: 870px;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
}

.link-footer-col h4, .link-footer-col p  {
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif !important;
    font-weight: 400 !important;
    font-size: 1em;

}

.link-footer-col h4  {

    color: #33add3;
    text-transform: uppercase;

}

.link-footer-col p  {

    color: #464646;
    font-size: 0.95em !important;
    line-height: 0.9em;
}

.certified {
  background-position: 0px -530px !important;
  padding: 280px;
  display: block;
}

.certified-img {
    margin-top: 80px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the `<nav>` class from `navbar navbar-simelsa` to:

```
navbar navbar-default navbar-simelsa
```

Make sure you have included bootstrap's CSS, jQuery and bootstrap's Javascript in the `<head>`:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.js"></script>
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Look at the docs for [navbar](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar) and [collapse.js](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse).

**HTML**:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-simelsa">
  <div class="container">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-simelsa">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-center" id="navbar-simelsa">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="inicio"><a href="#">Inicio</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nosotros"><a href="#">Nosotros</a>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown servicios">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Servicios <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a>
            </li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a>
            </li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="productos"><a href="#">Productos</a>
        </li>
        <li class="noticias"><a href="#">Noticias</a>
        </li>
        <li class="contacto"><a href="#">Contacto</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <li class="lang navbar-right nav navbar-nav"><a href="#">ESP | ENG</a>
      </li>
    </div>
    <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

See **[Example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MYZMMo)**.

Comment: Hi, i put the default class that you told me and my class navbar-simelsa to make my own styles, but in my styles there are a thing that it's broken the process. I put the styles above, check it to told me what it's broke the collapse menu. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to keep class `navbar-default` in `<nav>` element:

```
<nav class="navbar navabar-default navbar-simelsa">
```

You can then override style with your own class `navbar-simelsa`

Comment: Hi, i put the default class that you told me and my class navbar-simelsa to make my own styles, but in my styles there are a thing that it's broken the process, it's only work when i delete all my own styles. I put the styles above, check it to told me what it's broke the collapse menu. Thanks a lot!

Comment: But i want to make the class "navbar-simelsa" in the nav, to make my own styles, in your fiddle it's only the default: "<nav class="navbar navbar-default">". Thanks